# Azure Data Factory What are CreateFolderComposeRuntimeVariables? And how are they created?

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-data-factory

I'm using a lookup to parameterize a copy activity to create folders in a blobcontainer.
For some reason the activiy created (beside the expected folders),I guess, system generated folders like "body('CreateFolderComposeRuntimeVariables')?.DS_ADLS_RAW_TEST_folder02b3a53c7b64498d97e9299531de64ec.FolderName"
Is there a way to disable this in the copy activity?

Hope someone can help me out!

Kind regards,

dts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I do not have any clue about how you have implemented the pipeline , i will guess . I have seen similar ask before and if I am not wrong "02b3a53c7b64498d97e9299531de64ec" is the guid for activity Id . Yes I think if you are implementing dynamic expression , its not correct and if you are not using DE , then may you need to use that .